# /bin/sh: sequelize: not found when I try to run express.js app with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, express, dockerfile, sequelize.js

I have this in the Dockerfile in the users-service directory.

```
FROM node:15-alpine

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN echo ">>>> $PWD"

RUN ls -lart

RUN yarn install

RUN ls -lart /app/node_modules/.bin

CMD yarn watch
```

Current directory is `/app` as expected. Sequelize binary is there in the `node_modules/.bin` folder. Result of `/app/node_modules/.bin` command is...

```
total 16
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Apr  9 18:35 uuid -> ../uuid/dist/bin/uuid
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            30 Apr  9 18:35 sequelize-cli -> ../sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            30 Apr  9 18:35 sequelize -> ../sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
....

services:
  users-service:
    build: './users-service'
    depends_on:
      - users-service-db
    environment:
      - DB_URI=mysql://root:**********@users-service-db/users_db?charset=UTF8
    ports:
      - 7100:7100
    volumes:
      - ./users-service:/app
    networks:
      - autostop

  users-service-db:
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=users_db
    restart: always  
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:3306:3306
    networks:
      - autostop

...
```

When I run `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build` it shows

```
$ yarn db:migrate && babel-watch -L src/index.js
users-service_1     | $ sequelize db:migrate
users-service_1     | /bin/sh: sequelize: not found
```

[image]

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding the entire `/app` directory in the image, including `/app/node_modules`.  I'd recommend deleting that block from `docker-compose.yml`.  (And then since you're running the fixed code in the image, you can `CMD yarn start` or something similar that doesn't watch the files that won't change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you map the volume, even the `node_modules` get overridden by the host folder. And if you don't have `node_modules` in the host source code it won't work. So what you want is to mask the container's `node_modules` folder, so it doesn't get impacted by host folder map

```yaml
....

services:
  users-service:
    build: './users-service'
    depends_on:
      - users-service-db
    environment:
      - DB_URI=mysql://root:**********@users-service-db/users_db?charset=UTF8
    ports:
      - 7100:7100
    volumes:
      - ./users-service:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - autostop

  users-service-db:
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=users_db
    restart: always  
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:3306:3306
    networks:
      - autostop
volumes:
  node_modules:
...
```

By mapping it to a named volume, will make sure that the internal folder is not impacted by your outer host mapped folder

Comment: When i map `node_modules` I'm getting this error. `ERROR: Named volume "node_modules:/app/node_modules:rw" is used in service "users-service" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

However, shouldn't it be mapped to `./users-service/node_modules`? Infact as you can see in the question I've tried to make sure if node_modules is there in `/app/node_modules`. It is there including the binaries..

Comment: You need to add `volumes` section at the end as I showed in my code. It needs to have same indentation level as for `version` and `services`

Comment: It worked. Could you please explain this `- node_modules:/app/node_modules` ? How is `app/node_modules` being mapped to the volume specified?

Comment: docker uses a layer volume, where each layer is combined and you fs is final view of the filesystem. So when you map `./app:/app` then app folder in your current folder will be mapped to `/app` inside the container. But this will overwrite the complete folder. Since we don't want that to happen, we map a named volume to `/app/node_modules`, this protects the `./app:/app` mount to override the `/app/node_modules`